# Python: make legend figure (legend only, no plot), based on a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I have a pandas Data Frame with HEX colour codes in one column, and qualitative variables in the other column. It is like this:

```
Colour  Phyla
#db5f57 Firmicutes_A
#dba157 Bacteroidota
#d3db57 Verrucomicrobiota
#57db5f Proteobacteria
#5791db Cyanobacteria
#a157db Synergistota
```

I am *not* interested in creating a plot with this colour map (such as barplots or scatterplots, no). I simply want to produce an image (PNG or JPEG) similar to a legend, containing the names of the variable next to coloured squares (whose colour should be equivalent to the HEX code in the DataFrame, of course). Something similar to the following:

[image]

I have experience with producing images with Seaborn and Matplotlib, which only return legends when we plot something.

How can I produce the legend from the dataframe?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It was not intended to be a bacterial lgbt flag!

Comment: See the `Comparison between X11/CSS4 and xkcd colors` section to get an idea, from the [matplotlib docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colors.html#comparison-between-x11-css4-and-xkcd-colors). Then you can plot it and make a picture from it.